# Get form values and labels and send it in a email

Tags: django, django-forms

Im trying to write a function for getting form values and their label so I can have them in a email body like this:

```
<p><strong>Labelvalue</strong>: formvalue</p>
```

Is that possible?

When I do "body = smart_unicode(form.cleaned_data)" I get the dict, but Im not sure what I could do to get the html like I want.

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (ADULT, 'Adult'),
        (CHILD, 'Child'),
    )
    type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, label='Adult or child')
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name')
    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(2012,1900,-1)), label='Birthdate')
    address = forms.CharField(label='Address')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
```

Views.py

```
def show_myform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = MyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            subject = "Testsubject"

            sender = form.cleaned_data['email']

            recipients = ['post@mydomain.com']

            body = smart_unicode(form.cleaned_data)

            msg = EmailMessage(subject, body, sender, recipients)
            msg.send()            
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')


    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render(request, 'form/myform.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could tray to render the html you need into the body variable. You also need a html template for your mail body:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
body = render_to_string('yourapp/mail_template.html', {'var1':var1, 'var2':var2})
```

You can pass whatever you need to your template context dictionary (here i used var1 and var2 for example). Then send mail like this:

```
msg = EmailMessage(subject, body, sender, recipients)
msg.send()
```

Hope this leads into the right direction.

Comment: Glad to hear, so accept an answer. All answers here look like you could use them, so choose one please :).

Comment: i want to do exactly the same thing. can u tell me how to use these two variables "var1" and "var2" in email template

Comment: Gareth00 posted his updated source at the bottom of this question. var1 and var2 can be anything you like to render into the template. Have a look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut

Answer (score 1):

Better way would be create template and use django's [render_to_string](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut) to get html string as body.

You can pass `form.cleaned_data` to the template to populate the template variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can render the email body in a separate template. Use the following if using Django 1.3 or newer:

```
{% for field in form %}
<p><strong>{{ field.label }}</strong>: {{ field.value }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

For more information refer to the BoundForm documentation in Django.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. render_to_string did the trick!

Here is my updated source:

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (ADULT, 'Adult'),
        (CHILD, 'Child'),
    )
    type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, label='Adult or child')
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name')
    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(2012,1900,-1)), label='Birthdate')
    address = forms.CharField(label='Address')
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
```

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage, EmailMultiAlternatives
from norskfamilie.forms import HealthForm
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def show_Myform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = MyForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            subject = "My subject"

            sender = form.cleaned_data['email']

            recipients = ['post@mydomain.com']

            rendered = render_to_string('email_body.html', {'form':form , 'form_headline':subject})

            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, rendered, sender, recipients)
            msg.attach_alternative(rendered, "text/html")
            msg.send()            
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')


    else:
        form = MyForm()

    return render(request, 'form/myform.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

email_body.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{ form_headline }}</h1>

        {% for field in form %}
            <p><strong>{{ field.label }}</strong>: {{ field.value }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```